# Code refactoring for my case

Tags: c#

What is the best way to refactor this code? Are there any better ways to recode this piece?

```
if (doc.fldUpphandlingFilerStatus != null)
{
    if (DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNotice ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedOriginalNotice ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNewNoticeWithOpicData ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNewNotice)
    {
        icon = IconType.UnpublishedNotice;
    }
    if (DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.PublishedNotice ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.PublishedOriginalNotice)
    {
        icon = IconType.PublishedNotice;
    }
    if (DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedContractAward ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedFile ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedFileOtherReason)
    {
        icon = IconType.UnpublishedDocument;
    }
    if (DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.PublishedAgreement ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.PublishedContractAward ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.PublishedCourtCase ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.PublishedFile ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.PublishedTender)
    {
        icon = IconType.PublishedDocument;
    }
    if (DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.PublishedFileAfterTimeLimit)
    {
        icon = IconType.UnpublishedTenderingPeriod;
    }
    if (DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedFileOtherReason)
    {
        icon = IconType.AlwaysUnpublished;
    }
    if (DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.EmptyFile ||
        DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.FileNotFound)
    {
        icon = IconType.BrokenDocument;
    }
    if (DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedLink)
    {
        icon = IconType.UnpublishedLink;
    }
    if (DocumentFileStatus == Enums.FileStatus.PublishedLink)
    {
        icon = IconType.PublishedLink;
    }
}
```

Comment: change some if into else if? lol

Comment: Have a look at tools for that like [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). The thing you want is too boring for a human.

Comment: For which GUI-Framework do you need to set the icon? WPF?

Comment: Aside from key value storages like some of the suggestions below, have you thought of using a good old switch-case-statement? Seems like you are basically checking which enum value does what so using a switch-case here would be the first thing I'd do (instead of using if in the first place).

Comment: I think this is more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<Enums.FileStatus, IconType> dict = new Dictionary<Enums.FileStatus, IconType>()
{
    { Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNotice , IconType.UnpublishedNotice },
    { Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedOriginalNotice , IconType.UnpublishedNotice },
    { Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNewNoticeWithOpicData , IconType.UnpublishedNotice },
    { Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNewNotice, IconType.UnpublishedNotice },
    { Enums.FileStatus.PublishedNotice ,IconType.PublishedNotice },
    { Enums.FileStatus.PublishedOriginalNotice,IconType.PublishedNotice },
    { Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedContractAward ,IconType.UnpublishedDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedFile ,IconType.UnpublishedDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedFileOtherReason, IconType.UnpublishedDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.PublishedAgreement ,IconType.PublishedDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.PublishedContractAward ,IconType.PublishedDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.PublishedCourtCase ,IconType.PublishedDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.PublishedFile ,IconType.PublishedDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.PublishedTender,IconType.PublishedDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.PublishedFileAfterTimeLimit,IconType.UnpublishedTenderingPeriod },
    { Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedFileOtherReason, IconType.AlwaysUnpublished },
    { Enums.FileStatus.EmptyFile , IconType.BrokenDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.FileNotFound, IconType.BrokenDocument },
    { Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedLink,IconType.UnpublishedLink },
    { Enums.FileStatus.PublishedLink,IconType.PublishedLink }
};

icon = dict[DocumentFileStatus];
```

Answer (score 3):

A switch statement?

```
switch (DocumentFileStatus)
{
    case Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNotice:
    case Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedOriginalNotice:
    case Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNewNoticeWithOpicData:
    case Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNewNotice:
        icon = IconType.UnpublishedNotice;
        break;
    case Enums.FileStatus.PublishedNotice:
    case Enums.FileStatus.PublishedOriginalNotice:
        icon = IconType.PublishedNotice;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create mapping Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<FileStatus, IconType> mapping = new Dictionary<FileStatus, IconType>
{
   {Enums.FileStatus.UnpublishedNotice, IconType.UnpublishedNotice}
   ...
}
```

And then get appropriate value as:

```
IconType icon;
if(!mapping.TryGetValue(DocumentFileStatus, out icon))
{
    icon = someDefaultValue;
}
```